# GUI-Runspaces-PoshRSJob module

Tags: powershell, user-interface, runspace

I have created also a thread in powershell.org asking for help but was directed in your great community in order to get help.
For reference the link is https://powershell.org/forums/topic/gui-runspaces-poshrsjob-module/  and tried to copy it here also for convenience
 but unfortunately it is too large so you should check in the above link for details.

The code may seem that it a LOT of code but it is just a gui containing two "special" buttons that support background jobs which are embedded in powershell studio.The purpose is to use PoshRSJob instead of background jobs.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is better if you post the code here and specify the problem in your question as it will be easier for SO users to find this question if they stumbled on the same problem. Also it is better if you can point the problem in the minimal code example.